# Xcode can't find interface declaration after running "pod install"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I've inherited an iOS project which uses cocoapods.

The repo includes the Pods directory with all the necessary pods frozen in time. If I clone the repo and build the app, all is fine. If I run `pod update` and then build, I get an error:

> Cannot find interface declaration for COOperation.

The issue seems to be with a library called CompositeOperations, which is pulled in from a specific git account (not from cocoapods directly - not sure if that matters but just trying to give as much info as possible). Xcode is finding the library just fine, but for some reason it's not loading the Class declared in the interface file.

It seems silly to me to include the Pods directory in the repo. I feel like developers should clone the repo and then issue `git install` in order to pull down all dependancies.

Any suggestions for what I need to tweak in order for Xcode to successfully build my project?

The actual error in `MessageScreenDataFetchOperation.h` is:

> /Users/user/src/myapp/myapp-iOS/Classes/Shared/Operations/MessageScreenDataFetchOperation.h:13:46:
>   Cannot find interface declaration for 'COOperation', superclass of
>   'MessageScreenDataFetchOperation'; did you mean 'NSOperation'?

And here's what `MessageScreenDataFetchOperation.h` looks like:

```
#import <CompositeOperations/COOperation.h>

@protocol GroupRef;

@interface MessageScreenDataFetchOperation : COOperation
- (id)initWithMessageId:(NSNumber *)messageId group:(id <GroupRef>)groupRef memberId:(NSNumber *)memberId;
@end
```

Here's my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target :MyTarget do
  pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'
  pod 'CompositeOperations', :git => 'https://github.com/stanislaw/CompositeOperations.git'

  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
  pod 'EKKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 2.0'
  pod 'RBStoryboardLink', '0.1.0'
  pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.0.0'
  pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', :git => 'https://github.com/stanislaw/youtube-ios-player-helper', :branch => '0.1.1-and-no-ads'
  pod 'SZTextView'

  pod 'MagicKit', :git => 'https://github.com/stanislaw/MagicKit'
  pod 'ECPhoneNumberFormatter', :git => 'https://github.com/enriquez/ECPhoneNumberFormatter.git'
  pod 'SSKeychain'
  pod 'Mantle'
  pod 'RSEnvironment', :git => 'https://github.com/rabovik/RSEnvironment'

  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

  # Analytics
  pod 'FlurrySDK', '5.1.0'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'

  pod 'NewRelicAgent'

  # Logging
  pod 'EchoLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/stanislaw/EchoLogger'
  pod 'AFNetworkingLogger', :git => 'https://github.com/stanislaw/AFNetworkingLogger'
end

target :MyTargetUnitTests do
  pod 'OCMock', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'Kiwi'
  pod 'JPSimulatorHacks', :git => 'https://github.com/plu/JPSimulatorHacks'
end
```

Comment: You should probably show your pod file, the declaration in question and how you're importing the lib...

Comment: thanks @l'L'l, I've pasted everything above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `CompositeOperations` without using pods? That pod seems outdated to cocoapods:
https://cocoapods.org/?q=CompositeOperations

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the version that was baked in to the Xcode project was a much older version. The Podfile didn't restrict by version number, so running 'pod update' updated the library to the latest version, which had significant changes, making it incompatible with my code base.

I figured it out by diffing `Podfile.lock` after running `pod update` and noticing the drastic difference in versions.

I went forward with deleting the Pods directory and the .xcworkspace file, but amended the Podile to restrict the library based off a specific tag.